# Error in executing function on matlab in linux server(machine learning)

Tags: matlab

An error occurred during deep learning matlab execution, so eval.m could not be executed normally.

> > run eval.m
> > Error using run
> > RUN cannot execute the file 'eval.m'. RUN requires a valid MATLAB script
> > I checked and checked the matlab code, but I don't know where the problem is.
> > What should I do to run run eval.m normally? please.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUDRq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brOi4.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va3Ho.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jykx.jpg)

#matlab

Comment: you are accidentally overriding matlab eval() function: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html
just change the name of it to something else which is not reserved